# SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data when trying to inser to mysql

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am using new to using AJAX and PHP I am trying to send a post request to a file called insertvalue.php. I already created the table and database. I am trying to grab the value from a jquery slider through ajax and then insert that value into the mysql table. After that, I want to return the results from the mysql table.

When I try running the script I get the error "SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data". I checked, and I am not sure what I did wrong. Any assistance would be appreciated. Thanks!

db_connect.php

```
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "private", "private", "private");
// fake credentials for posting

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
   echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$createTable = "
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ClassValues (
        question VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
        slider_value INT(50) NOT NULL
    )
";

 if ($connect->query($createTable) === TRUE) {
   //  echo "Table ClassValues created successfully";
 } else {
   echo "Error creating table: " . $connect->error;
 }
```

js file with ajax to send js to php

```
 $.ajax({
     url: 'php/insertvalue.php',
     data: { 'one': value }, // slider value 
     type: 'post',
     dataType: 'json',
     success: function(x) {
         alert(x.one);
     },
     error: function(request, status, error) {
         alert(error);
     }
 });
```

insertvalue.php

```
include 'db_connect.php';  // database connection

$one = $_POST['one'];
$array = array('one'=>$one);

echo json_encode($array);

$query = "INSERT INTO ClassValues (question, slider_value) VALUES('Question 1', $one)";
mysql_query($query);

$selection = "SELECT slider_value FROM ClassValues";
$result = $conn->query($selection);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "slider_value" . $row["slider_value"] . "<br/>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
```

Comment: `dataType` is the type of data you're expecting back. So you're telling jQuery to parse the response as JSON. But insertvalue.php isn't returning JSON, it's returning html.

Comment: Ok. Should I edit the datatype to html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your JavaScript code, you are expecting JSON encoded data from the server.

Hence, you have to make sure your server will respond with **only one JSON encoded result, per each client request**. The parser will not understand mixture of JSON encoded data with text like `{ "one": "one" }slider_value` or mixture of JSON encoded data with another JSON encoded data like `{ "one": "one" }{ "two": "two" }`.

To achieve this, you need to convert all your `echo 'some result'` statements to `$result = 'some result'`. At the end of your script, you will then encode and echo the final result, e.g.: `{ "result": "Success", "message": "Data inserted successfully"}`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. This is very helpful